# Turing machine that accepts strings with an equal beginning and end length

Tags: finite-automata, turing-machines, computation

I need help creating a single tape deterministic Turing machine for this language  [image]

here I am not sure how to determine which strings the TM will accept. How can I make the machine accept strings where a=c? because the b part has elements from both a and c.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @BenoîtGuédas yes, but I dont know the key observation of which strings will be accepted, theres some trick to it. its only know for sure to be a C if 3 comes after 2, and its a B if 1 comes after a 2, but for all the other cases I am not sure how to determine where the B starts and ends and where to C starts and ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try do adapt a machine which accepts palidromes: you read a character to the left. If it belongs to {0,1} you delete it and go to the right (the last character). If the character belongs to {2,3}, you delete it and go back to the left (the first character). Repeat it until you find a character which does not belong to the "a" or "c" side (and check the last character if you were on the left), the remaining characters should belong to the "b" block.